# Using old ASP.NET MVC5 Identity in the latest .NET 6.0 Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

We have an existing system that is being used by thousands of users for the last six years. It was built back in 2015 using **MVC5** (ASP.NET Framework v4.6). This app uses Identity Framework for authentication and authorization of users.

Now we want to break down the existing MVC5 web app implementation into a backend API and a frontend React.js app.

For the backend, we want to keep using the old database and develop the web API with the latest **.NET 6.0** framework.

I understand that the hashing technique in the Identity Framework has changed over time. The user authentication cannot be done using the latest identity framework's UserManager and SignInManager classes with the old MVC5 Identity Framework based database.

What should be done in order to authenticate users in .NET 6.0 based Web API that uses the old MVC5 Identity Framework based database?

Answer (score 0):

For the Web API you can add a [JWT](https://jwt.io/) based authentication using your MVC5 Identity Framework as back end.

From the Identity Framework just get if the username and pass is correct and then based on that issue a JWT token. Users with this token will be able to consume your APIs.

This JWT token part would sit between the Web API and the service where you can validate the identity.

Comment: Basically something like the Identity Server app that will issue a JWT token. The JWT token will be requested by and stored on the client-side (react.js) app. This token will then be passed to the Web API with every request. Right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: thanks. Can you please suggest any other approach?